# python3 how to search a log file

Tags: python, python-3.x

So for an assignment I have to read a log file with entries similar to the ones listed below.

```
s12773390  dtremote     ::1::1:6         Sat Mar 26 14:03 - 15:08  (01:04)
kthao2    dtremote     ::1::1:6         Sat Mar 26 11:25 - 11:32  (00:06)
jwoodcock  dtremote     ::1::1:3         Fri Mar 25 23:23 - 23:29  (00:06)
```

Then I have to find a specific user and the date they first logged on. So far I have come up with.

```
loginDataFile = open('logindata.dat', 'r')
loginDataList = loginDataFile.readlines()
jwoodcockLogin = [x for x in loginDataList if 'jwoodcock' in x]
print(jwoodcockLogin[len(jwoodcockLogin - 1)])
```

So far this gets me the list element which they first logged on but, I just want the date from the log entry, not the entire thing.

Answer (score 1):

If your first three fields are guaranteed not to have spaces, you can do:

```
username, type, address, timestamp = jwoodcockLogin[-1].split(None, 3)

print(timestamp)
```

which will split on whitespace three times, leaving the rest of the string after the third whitespace run as a single string.

I'll note, you're wasting a ton of memory here (if the log file is large), since you store the whole thing in memory, even when you only care about a single line.

A simpler solution might be:

```
lasttimestamp = None
# Use with statement to guarantee the file is closed promptly (on block exit)
with open('logindata.dat') as loginDataFile:
    # file objects are lazy iterators of their lines, no need to call
    # .readlines() and eagerly slurp the whole thing into (limited) memory
    for line in loginDataFile:
        # Extract username and timestamp, with _ indicating fields that must
        # exist, but we don't care about otherwise
        username, _, _, timestamp = line.split(None, 3)
        if username == 'jwoodcock':
            lasttimestamp = timestamp

if lasttimestamp is not None:
    print(lasttimestamp)
else:
    print("User not found in log")
```

That never stores more than the current line being processed and the last timestamp seen for the user, so a 1 MB log file and a 10 GB log file only differ in time to scan, you don't risk running out of memory.

Comment: I'm tempted to answer with a subprocess of `grep` and `tail` ;)

Comment: Thanks for the info Ill give this a try.

Comment: @cricket_007 and why don't you do that? Only because the tags suggest it have to be a Python solution? subprocess IS Python ... With grep and tail that looping stuff is away and you have a one-liner :) .